# Extending HTML5 geolocation with custom access points

Tags: html, geolocation, extend

I'm experimenting with HTML5 geolocation, and would like to improve the accuracy, by assigning the exact GPS coordinate of some custom access points.
How can I add these access points, and their exact position to the current database?

If I cannot add custom APs to the database, can I view the source code used by Google (and others), to calculate the position, according to APs and their signal strength.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skyhook Wireless (one of the three main location look-up services, along with Apple and Google) has [an online form](http://www.skyhookwireless.com/howitworks/submit_ap.php) for specifying the geolocation of a particular access point.

I'm not aware of anything similar for Google Location Services or for Apple's internal list of WiFi networks and locations.

If you want to you could implement your own server to do the calculations. Firefox, for example, makes it easy to change the server in its about:config. And there seems to be a [loose standard](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/geolocation_network_protocol.html) (at least from Google, but this may also apply elsewhere) for these simple JSON requests.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I had hoped to tap into some sort of API, but since this isn't available I will find another way.